# Warn when an array has the same enum case

Tags: arrays, swift, enums, compiler-warnings

I have an enum

```
public enum Option {
    case first(CGFloat),
    case second(CGFloat),
    case third(Bool),
    case fourth
}
```

And a function that takes an array of these enums

```
func gimme(the options: [Option]) -> Result
```

What I'd like to do, is warn / error when someone adds two of the same case, but I don't know how.

```
gimme(the: [first(1.0), second(2.0), third(false)]) // fine

gimme(the: [first(1.0), first(2.0), third(false]) // not fine
```

It's not about the associated values, just that you want to send the same case twice.. I'm assuming it'd an extension like...

```
extension Array where Element == Option {

   // No idea how to do this
}
```

but I'm not sure what I need to override.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only uniq options without caring about arguments then just change your function. To be able pass only interested options you may use default values + optionals if you don't want option at all:

```swift
func gimme(first: CGFloat? = nil, second: CGFloat? = nil, third: Bool? = nil, ...)
gimme(third: True)
```

```swift
func gimme(first: CGFloat = 0, second: CGFloat = 0, third: Bool = false, ...)
gimme(second: 10.2)
```

If you want to be able to pass your options together between objects, wrap them in struct:

```swift
struct GimmedArguments {
    var first: CGFloat?
    var second: CGFloat?
    var third: Bool?
}

func gimme(the arguments: GimmedArguments) { ... }
```

<s>It can be problematic to catch in compile time, since how you will handle when used variables instead of plain values:</s>

```swift
gimme(the: var1, var2, var3)
```

You can try to write some `swiftlint` rules or custom script, but IMHO it may be overkill.

Instead you could add runtime check as:

```swift
func myFunction(array: [Int]) {
    precondition(Set(array).count == array.count, "Array should not contain same elements")
}
```

If you just want to make sure that your function called with uniq elements, use `Set` instead. It will guaranteed that all elements uniq.

Comment: Be aware that you'd need to make `Option` conform to `Hashable` and even then, the default synthetised conformance would take the associated values into account as well when comparing two `Option` instances. So your suggested solution wouldn't work for OP's requirements.

Comment: @DávidPásztor good point, I not understood question right. Will change answer

Comment: Check if an array has the same enum in it twice... answer make it a struct? No, dude, I need this thing to compile warn when you add more than one of them to an array. It’s an abstract question. The compile warning on the array is the part I’m looking for.

Comment: @Magoo imho, unless you want to write your own script, extension for compiler, you can't achieve it. This is closest one to your requirements

Comment: @Magoo, `Swift` is not expressive enough to do so. You may do this in `Agda` or `F-star`, but not in `Swift`